# How to insert date parameter in a format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss' or 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' using Nifi flow to Oracle sql?

Tags: apache-nifi

i have a nifi flow that converts a log from mq, converts it into jason and puts the data in a database. (a picture of the workflow is attached)

although i use jolt in order to reshape it, no matter how i parse the date-time component, nifi sends an error message that the time component cannot be converted to a timestamp.

how can i overcome this problem?

thank you very much!
[image]

Comment: normally all databases support format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. please edit your question and add details: what processor you are using to insert data into oracle, what is the format of data in flow file prior insertion, ...

Comment: HI i edited the question, hopefully it is now clearer. thank you!

Comment: please show the result of ConvertJsonToSql and exact error message from log file

Comment: i have tried many combinations for the component structure, and some of them looked like these: "ZTR" : "202008145802"
"ZTR" : "09082020103620Q538ML00"
"ZTR" : "20200802174200Q538M"
"ZTR":"04/08/2020 17:21:09"
"ZTR" : "2020-08-0217.20.22Q538ML00"
"ZTR" : "28-07-2020 16.54.55"
"ZTR" : "2020-07-28 16:54:55"
"ZTR":"2020/08/04 17:21:09"

Comment: the message was as follows: 542c3bba-4634-1b21-8d23-3a07a5c27833
PutSQL[id=542c3bba-4634-1b21-8d23-3a07a5c27833] Failed to update database for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=acf29d94-fb27-4ddb-a2bc-a3789426aba9,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1596023874465-572, container=default, section=572], offset=721034, length=896],offset=0,name=8a6332df-fa24-4396-a1d9-b3b7be28a121,size=896] due to The value of the sql.args.39.value is '02/08/2020 11:59:23', which cannot be converted to a timestamp; routing to failure:

Comment: java.sql.SQLDataException: The value of the sql.args.39.value is '02/08/2020 11:59:23', which cannot be converted to a timestamp

Comment: read about NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter in oracle

Comment: Although I'm sure I've already tried this format, I'll try it again. There is no data flow at the moment so tomorrow morning I will check it and i will let you know if it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: What was the solution to the date insertion format?